# BigQuery upload timestamp error from csv file

Tags: java, csv, timestamp, google-bigquery

I have problems uploading a csv file with a timestamp field through the java api. The field in the csv file is **2017-10-30 09:00:00 Europe/Madrid** and the error that occurs is:
**Unrecognized timezone: Europe / Madrid; Could not parse '2017-10-30 09:00:00 Europe / Madrid' as datetime*
My schema is:

```
_PARTITIONTIME  TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE    
fechaHora   TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE    
idCliente   STRING  NULLABLE    
idOrigen    STRING  NULLABLE    
numPedidosPendientes    INTEGER NULLABLE    
numPedidosPreparados    INTEGER NULLABLE    
numLineasPendientes INTEGER NULLABLE    
numLineasPreparadas INTEGER NULLABLE
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does it work if you use the `+1` notation instead of the time zone name? Or do you get the same error?

Answer (score 2):

I have already solved it, in java it is necessary to put **2017-10-30 09:00:00+01** instead of **2017-10-30 09:00:00 Europe/Madrid**
Thank you.